Suddenly getting error message: Safety checks failed: Failed to get program path
Suddenly getting message: Safety checks failed: Failed to get program path error message during anchor build
anchor version 0.30.0
solana version 0.18.17


I ran into the same issue, which seems to be related to the Anchor IDL build step. Using anchor-cli 0.30.1 solved the issue for me.

I tried but still getting same error

If you get this error after running anchor build, you can fix it by upgrading your anchor-cli to v0.30.1:
avm install 0.30.1

On the other hand, if you get this error from Rust Analyzer, it means you have the idl-build feature enabled in Rust Analzyer settings (most likely all features). In this scenerio, there are multiple solutions:

Define ANCHOR_IDL_BUILD_PROGRAM_PATH env variable to equal your program's directory path in Rust Analyzer settings (cargo.extraEnv)
Do not enable all features (cargo.features = "all")

Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/3042

Had all rust analyzer features turned on using the following line in my settings.json
{
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.features": "all",
}

Removing the line got rid of the errors for me

I'm getting this when importing another crate that uses anchor 0.30.1.
xxx = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx", branch = "anchor_301_upgrade", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }

When building a program that relies on this, it starts giving me the path not found error from anchor 30.

The anchor has released a new version, updated it, and fixed the issue.
https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.1

No it's not working I am using the latest versions only anchor-cli 0.30.11 and solana-cli 1.18.17 (src:b685182a; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs), even try adding anchor-lang-idl = { version = "0.1.1", features = ["convert"] } to Cargo.toml file, but still not working
